# Bourne shell date command string use as variable - returning 0

Tags: shell, sh

on Android Linux - I want to assign a var to a date value - but I can't figure out how to get (Busybox?) the shell to not return 0 for my desired format.

```
let hourfiletag="$(date +%j%H)"
echo $hourfiletag
let tagtwo="D$hourfiletag"
echo $tagtwo
let tagthree="D${hourfiletag}H"
echo $tagthree

let hourfiletag="$(date +D%jH%H)"
echo $hourfiletag
let tagtwo="D$hourfiletag"
echo $tagtwo
let tagthree="D${hourfiletag}H"
echo $tagthree
```

When I run this, here is the output I get:

```
$ ./date1.sh                                        
34011
0
0
0
0
0
```

The date command can produce exactly what I want:

```
$ date +D%jH%H                                      
D340H11
```

But I am unable to make it a variable that I can use in a file cp operation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is used to **Evaluate arithmetic expressions**

You can just use:

```
hourfiletag=`date '+D%jH%H'`
```

OR:

```
hourfiletag=$(date '+D%jH%H')

echo "$hourfiletag"
D340H12
```

Comment: ok, that's it. Will accept after the 10 minutes requirement... I think at some point I copied/pasted a line from a tutorial with 'let' on it and didn't consider it. Thanks.

Comment: The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g. foo=`command`. The foo=$(command) syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 0):

No need `let` at all :

```
$ cat a
hourfiletag="$(date +%j%H)"
echo $hourfiletag
tagtwo="D$hourfiletag"
echo $tagtwo
tagthree="D${hourfiletag}H"
echo $tagthree

hourfiletag="$(date +D%jH%H)"
echo $hourfiletag
tagtwo="D$hourfiletag"
echo $tagtwo
tagthree="D${hourfiletag}H"
echo $tagthree
```

Output:

```
shell@android:/ $ sh /storage/sdcard0/a
34018
D34018
D34018H
D340H18
DD340H18
DD340H18H
```